# correlation with multiple constraints

Tags: excel-formula

How am I able to calculate the correlation of two ranges where I have two or more constraints.

**Example:** I want the correlation of A and B (table starts in `A1`)

```
A B C
1 2 x
3 4 z
5 6 x
7 8 y
9 0 z
1 2 x
3 4 y
5 6 y
7 8 z
```

I am able to calculate the correlation of:

- all values `=CORREL(A2:A10,B2:B10)`
- only values, which have a `x` in column C `{=CORREL(IF(C2:C10="x",A2:A10),B2:B10)}`

But how to do this with all values, having `x` or `y` in column C?

I tried several ways, but can't figure out:

- `{=CORREL(IF(C2:C10={"x","y"},A2:A10),B2:B10)}`
- used `SUMPRODUCT` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (not tested)

```
=CORREL(IF((C2:C10="x")+(C2:C10="y")>0,A2:A10),B2:B10)
```

or

```
=CORREL(IF((C2:C10="x")+(C2:C10="y")>0,A2:A10),IF((C2:C10="x")+(C2:C10="y")>0,B2:B10))
```

Both these formulas are array formula so commit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: OT: For everyone interested, `=CORREL(IF((C2:C10<>"x")+(C2:C10<>"y")-1>0,A2:A10),B2:B10)` (of course) works fine to exclude values

Answer (score 0):

You could try

`={CORREL(((C2:C10="x")+(C2:C10="y"))*(A2:A10),((C2:C10="x")+(C2:C10="y"))*(B2:B10))}`

Or

> `CORREL(Index(((C2:C10="x")+(C2:C10="y"))*(A2:A10),),Index(((C2:C10="x")+(C2:C10="y"))*(B2:B10),))`

Comment: Both work perfectly the first one is a matrix function the second one no. It is a shame you are not able to execute them